# String-Object converter

Tags: java, javafx, converters, tostring

I want a method that can convert an object (with a few parameters String or int) in a String, and more importantly, convert that String back in an object. Do you know any way to develop a converter for this purpose?

The problem is that the object is a DTO used by other developpers so I can't modify the `toString()` method. Thus I created my own method toString, but I don't know how can I reliably make a converter working both ways. I thought about several solutions (storing the objects in a map, etc), but they all seem unclear to read/understand. Is there any usual way to do it that every experienced programmers would understand in a blink of an eye what it does?

EDIT: Well, I know serialization, but my question wasn't clear, I'm sorry. The fact is that I want to display the objects in a ListView (JavaFX), to make them readable, like String "N°:xxxx; Version : 1", serialized objects aren't really esthetic nor readable.

So my final solution is something more like:

```
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ProductDto>, ListCell<ProductDto>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<ProductDto> call(final ListView<ProductDto> productDtoListView) {
            return new ListCell<ProductDto>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(final ProductDto productDto, final boolean b) {
                    if(productDto!=null){
                        setText(fromProductDtoToString(productDto));
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

This way, I store the objects themselves in the ListView, and can still display a fairly esthetic String  representing the object.

Thanks for your time.

Fabien

Comment: Convert an Object to String , in what sense ?

Comment: Have you tried serializing/deserializing to printable formats such as JSON/XML?

Answer (score 3):

You can for example use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to convert object to [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and vice versa. Check this article [How To Convert Java Object To / From JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

If you want, you can use [XML binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) too.

In general, there are number of serialization libraries/approaches:

- [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (for XML but not for JSON)
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (for JSON)
- [Jackson xml module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) (faster than XStream)
- [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) (a fast, compact binary serialization format)
- [Smile](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (a binary format that comes with Jackson 1.6 and later).
- Java Object Serialization.
- [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) seems solid, runs at 2x the speed of XStream, but requires more configuration effort
- [YamlBeans](http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/)
- [SnakeYAML](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/)

Jackson JSON, Kryo, and Jackson Smile are all significantly faster than good old Java Object Serialization, by about 3x to 4.5x.  XStream is on the slow side.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Truth is my question wasn't very clear (I edited it), I found a solution without serialization.